# Should I use Patterns and Practices for SharePoint 2013 On Prem and stick with it for Branding

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin, deployment, branding

The idea behind remote publishing of Patterns and Practices looks very good at best but I am having second thoughts using that pattern for deploying my custom branding to the OnPrem SharePoint farm.

We were introduced with the Design manager as the best alternative for feature framework based deployment, But it has some serious limitation when deploying those prod or qa environment and others. Due to these limitations I moved back to the feature frameworks based deployment to move the design files between environments.

I had few questions about the PnP that I have typed below, Please share your thoughts if you have any.

- Is this PnP framework something I can trust for the future or will it
  get killed sometime later for a better thing?
- Is feature framework still that better idea for preventing duplicate design packages every time when you deploy to Prod? (Other thing that I have been doing
  deploy to the Network share folder of the QA Server and seemed it might not be that bad)

Sites

- PnP: http://dev.office.com/patterns-and-practices
- Control branding deployment: https://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/OfficeDevPnP/PnP-Add-In-Transformation-Training-module-3-Branding-with-add-in-model

Comment: I would yes, the people directly involved with the development are showing you how to use supportable, non farm destroying methodologies to customize your platform.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to retract my doubts on the PnP program, As I have seen it grow leaps and bounds with the support of the wonderfull community not just inside microsoft but throughout the world

There is not a day goes by that I have not used the tools provided by PnP program in the last few months, specially the [PnP Powershell](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell)  I have used it for replicating the List and Library creating and having a perfect documnentation of my farm from the start to finish.

Thanks to the team and I have learnt the new modern way of developing web apps (React, Gulp and Typescript) with which I wouldn't have been motivated my self to learn things beyond Server Object Model.